# Regular expression in Ruby dynamic creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to create a dynamic regular expression in my Rails application. I have a table called `foo` in my database. `foo` consists of two columns, `id` and `phrase` which is just varchar(255). I want to be able to make one giant expression with all the 'phrase' instances joined and see if an incoming parameter matches any of the words in phrase. I thought something like the following might do it, but it doesn't seem to work proper. What am I doing wrong?

```
# get all phrases
phrases = Foo.all.map(&:phrase)

regex = Regexp.new phrases.join('|')

if params[:some_text] =~ regex
  # something in params[:some_text] matched at least one phrase
end
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do ``Foo.where(:phrase => params[:some_text]).present?``

Comment: Because if ``params[:some_text] == "Hello World"`` and phrase is just 'World', it will not work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think the issue is some of the phrases in my db are are ``ba$$`` (I'm trying to do a simple search and replace on elite speak) and characters such as $ and ! won't match as literals. Is there a way to translate them into literals vs their special regular expression meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

> **union(pat1, pat2, ...) → new_regexp**
>   **union(pats_ary) → new_regexp**
>
> Return a `Regexp` object that is the union of the given patterns, i.e., will match any of its parts. The patterns can be `Regexp` objects, in which case their options will be preserved, or `String`s.

So just this:

```
regex = Regexp.union(phrases)
```

For example:

```
>> phrases = %w[pancakes egg$]
=> ["pancakes", "egg$"]
>> puts Regexp.new(phrases.join('|')).inspect
/pancakes|egg$/
>> puts Regexp.union(phrases).inspect
/pancakes|egg\$/
```

Note the escaped `$` in the `union` version. There's also [`Regexp.quote`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) (AKA `Regexp.escape`) if you need to selectively escape particular strings. Generally you don't want to just mash a bunch of random strings together to build a regex, the regex syntax characters will get you every time; use `Regex.union` for a big alternation or send your pieces through `Regex.escape` before putting them together.

You could also do a LIKE query if you wanted to keep it inside the database:

```
Foo.where('phrase like ?', "%#{params[:some_text]}%")
```

or skip all the pattern matching stuff and its escaping problems altogether and do a simple string position check:

```
Foo.where('position(? in phrase) != 0', params[:some_text])
```

Both of these will do table scans but so will your `Foo.all`.

Answer (score -1):

```
1.8.7 > phrases = ['one', 'two', 'three']
 => ["one", "two", "three"] 
1.8.7 > regex = Regexp.new phrases.join('|')
 => /one|two|three/ 
1.8.7 > puts 'match' if "a one b" =~ regex
match
```

Perhaps there is something else going on?  What you're doing works for me, removing AR from the equation.

Comment: This will fail if `phrases` contains something like `'string$'` as you're not escape the regex characters.